# psql: Run commands in batch mode

Tags: postgresql-9.3, psql

Consider a `.sql` file with a few selects and updates. I would like to run this file from a script using the `psql` utility:

```
psql -h whatever.rds.amazonaws.com -U user dbname -f commands.sql
```

The problem is that I get an interactive screen with the results of the query and an `(0 rows)(END)`, which requires pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> in order to go back to the normal shell.

I have tried using `--echo-all` and/or `--single-transaction` following the [psql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html), with no luck.

How do I run my `sql` file in non-interactive mode, only displaying the results an exiting the script?

Comment: What platform are you on? That's not normal.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS, and it happens both on direct invocation and from a bash script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For batch operation I generally use:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -P pager=off --single-transaction
```

... however, generally `psql` should detect that stdout is not a terminal and automatically turn `pager` off if you're redirecting its stdout.